# How to use Expression.Or() in Castle ActiveRecord?

Tags: activerecord, castle-activerecord

Please, explain me how to use Experssion.Or() in FindAll function.

for example i have 2 conditions - Expression.Like("Text", "%coolstuff%") and

Expression.Eq("FromInternet", false)

how to use them together via "or"?

Comment: It looks like you're using an old version of ActiveRecord. I recommend getting the latest from http://sourceforge.net/projects/castleproject/files/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// ...
Expression.Or(
  Expression.Like("text", "%arbitrary%"),
  Expression.Eq("FromInternet", false)
)
// ...
```